# Getting different response for the same API and parameters in Jmeter/Postman

Tags: api, jmeter, load-testing, postman, web-api-testing

I have used login API to test in Jmeter.

For that I have passed request:

POST  URL: .... POST data parameters: "email Address": "a@gmail.com","password": "ad332017"

For the above request i am getting two different responses.

**On postman:** I am getting response with status code 200 OK (which is expected too)

**ON Jmeter** I am getting response: Response code: 307 Response message: Temporary Redirect.

Anyone who can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Given you make the same requests (no matter which tool is being used) you should be getting the same responses so most probably there are differences in JMeter/Postman configuration. You can capture the requests sent by JMeter and Postman using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), figure out the differences and amend JMeter configuration to eliminate them

Also be aware that you can record your Postman request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), this way JMeter will capture the request sent by Postman and generate the releavant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler along with [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

1. Configuring JMeter for recording is pretty easy, the fastest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   - From JMeter's main menu choose: `File - Templates - Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand `Workbench - HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Launch Postman to use JMeter as a proxy

   ```
   %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Postman\app-x.x.x\Postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
   ```
3. Run your request in Postman
4. JMeter should capture the request under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Postman is doing automatic redirection for you. JMeter is not.

You can toggle the `automatically follow redirects` setting by  going to `Settings -> General` in Postman and see if it you are getting a different response.

You can open `DevTools` in the Postman App (`View -> Show DevTools`) and go to the network tab and observe the flow of requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried as per suggested by you but still it showing same error can you please suggest any other solution it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using domain name n the post url, give the IP address instead of domain name.